# Почему не работает вращение объекта через rigidbody2d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем, мне нужно генерировать шестиугольники с рандомным вращением.
Я сделал следующие (код из метода Start): 
`rb.rotation = Random.Range(0, 360);`
Однако вращение объекта всегда одинаковое, хотя я пытался вывести в консоль значение, которое устанавливается rigidbody. Все безуспешно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то не обратил внимания на то, что речь о `Rigidbody2D`. `Rigidbody2D.rotation` - это действительно 1 число в градусах в диапазоне `[0..360]`. Проверил данный код у себя - все работает:

```
public class RB2D_Rotator : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().rotation = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
    }
}
```

Перепроверьте свой код и вывод в консоли, возможно, вы потеряли ссылку на объект Rigidbody2D

---

**Все, что находится ниже, относится к Rigidbody, не к Rigidbody2D, и к вопросу не относится**, но пусть будет, вдруг кому пригодится.

Идем в документацию [Rigidbody.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html) и видим, что данный класс хранит вращение в виде Quaternion'а. Так что строка `rb.rotation = Random.Range(0, 360);` делает неправильно сразу 2 вещи:

1. Quaternion состоит из 4х значений, `Random.Range(...);` возвращает 1 float число
2. Все составляющие кватерниона лежат в диапазоне [0..1], вы же передаете переменную в диапазоне [0..360]. Это неправильно, что в этом случае будет происходить - не важно.

Как работает кватернион и что туда нужно вообще передавать - тема сложная и обширная, поэтому не ломайте себе голову и используйте вращение через градусы:

`rb.MoveRotation(Random.Range(0, 360));`

Comment: Это странно, но ютубер Brackeys именно так и делает

Comment: Он передает вещественное число в rb.rotaition и у него все работает https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8MzsDBI5EI&t=692s

Comment: @user319478, мой косяк - у 3D и 2D версий разная реализация поворота, исправлю ответ в ближайшем времени.

Comment: Чудеса. Вращение через rigidbody2d не работает. Хоть ему и устанавливаются различные значения (я выводил их в консоль). Объект не вращается. Однако, изменив функцию на transform.Rotate(), все четко

Comment: @user319478, `Rotate` то понятное дело будет работать, странно, тут надо иметь дело со всей иерархией, в любом случае используйте тогда `Rotate`.

Comment: а есть вообще разница в том как вращать объект?

Comment: @user319478, `Rotate` вращает объект учитывая текущее вращение, `rotation` - это "голое" вращение объекта и вам самим нужно учитывать вращение объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу оставить комментарий, поэтому напишу тут. А чем плохо вращение через transform.Rotate? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: Мне просто интересен факт того, почему вращение через rigidbody не происходит

Comment: Тогда ответ дать не могу, не пользовался никогда вращением через rigidbody :D